# A Recent Mass Extinction--How Long Must Life Reel Itself Back In?

Tags: evolution, post-apocalypse

In our understanding of mass extinction and adaptive radiation, we have found that life can't and doesn't bounce back right away.  They take time.  It took life eight to ten million years to recover from the worst mass extinction in Earth's history.  In the aftermath of the Mesozoic-Cenozoic Extinction Event, life bounced back after at least 100,000 years.

But what about a more recent mass extinction?  Would life today still be on the verge of recovery if there were an extinction event merely five million years ago?

[An Earlier Pleistocene = Mass Extinction?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34032/an-earlier-pleistocene-mass-extinction)

Comment: We're probably in the middle of one, the [Holocene extinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocene_extinction), so just wait and you'll find out! ;)

Comment: If the link is any consideration, what you've said doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer. Just a bit of dark humor.

Comment: An interesting question to explore is what metric are you judging the "health" of life with?  It can be remarkably hard to do so without accidentally assuming that we humans are the "goal" of life or something similar.  Much of "life" is change, and it's good at it.  I don't know what metric you want to use, but I do see an opportunity to link this comic http://www.funnyjunk.com/funny_pictures/2582563/Mother .  I think it does put a nice spin on these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how much of the currently prevalent species die out during the 'Mass extinction' and how badly it affects the general world climate.

During the [Permian-Triassic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permian%E2%80%93Triassic_extinction_event) event ca. 250 Mio years ago, a staggering 90% of all oceanic species (not animals -- *species*) died out, and about 70% of all vertebrates plus 50% of all insect species. That one took 10Mio years to recover from, so that a somewhat proper biodiversity could be reestablished. It also made way for completely new types of animals -- similar to the extinction [of the dinosaurs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cretaceous%E2%80%93Paleogene_extinction_event) 66 Mio years ago which caused approximately 75% of all species to go extinct.

If you've got an extinction event of such proportions only 5 Mio years ago, then we'd probably still be in the recovery phase to restore biodiversity.

What that means: there are fewer species than normal. It does *not* mean that there are fewer plants/organisms/animals! Earth will be as green and teeming with life as ever -- 5Mio years are a lot of time, after all, to recover from a severe loss of population. You'll just find a lot more 'monocultures' than today in the wild. And you might not have such specialized combinations like a plant whose flower is shaped in such a specific way that exactly 2 certain types of Kolibri can get to its nectar. There also might be a few spots current fauna hasn't reconquered yet, but after 5Mio years they will be few. There already has been quite a bit of time for selection to adapt to extreme living conditions, after all.

Additionally, next to highly specialized/developed species, the amount of highly intelligent species  will be small compared to today. Extinction events tend to hit the biggest (=largest) species first, not least of all because they have such a comparably small population. Intelligence though demands a certain body size to get the brain large enough. And an intelligent brain also demands a lot of evolution. After the dinosaur-extinction, it took about [25Mio years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_cetaceans) for the ancestors of dolphins and whales to be born. They were only a tiny bit faster than the [30Mio years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ape) to get the ape family from the regular monkeys, and then about 20Mio more years to get from apes to hominids (humanity's ancestors).

So, if you are hoping for humanity or at least humanity's ancestors to have survived such a large-scale extinction event -- well, you're pretty much SOL there. They probably belonged to some of the first species to starve / freeze to death / ...

Comment: Highly developed does not imply intelligent. As a somewhat extreme example, one could easily argue that [tardigrades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade) are highly developed -- after all, they are *very* well adapted to their environment, and have managed adaptations that few other species get close to -- but I think it would be quite a larger stretch to call them intelligent. Intelligence only arises and is maintained when the intelligence itself provides a clear evolutionary benefit that offsets the very real costs. That's why high intelligence is relatively rare in kingdom Animalia.

Comment: Yeah, made the old logical error here -- intelligence implies high development, but not the other way round. Still, you will have neither highly developed nor highly intelligent species after such a short time.

Comment: "Depends on how much of the currently prevalent species die out during the 'Mass extinction' and how badly it affects the general world climate."  I was thinking 50% of land species and 65% of aquatic species.

Comment: Yeah. That will probably do it to apply the 'Death to all Large, Developed, or Intelligent Animals' rule here. The biodiversity might have already recovered, but you will still need to start pretty much from scratch. You might get a jump-start of a couple Mio years on several of the 'higher' evolution line, though.

Comment: If you are talking about starting *today*, humans actually have a vast advantage over all other species, having expanded into virtually every habitat from mountaintops to desert to tropical rainforest to the arctic using only neolithic technology. Five million years ago our most distant ancestors were only starting on the path towards humanity, so would be a small subspecies in a limited environmental niche and far less likely to survive.